# Cohen's d and standard deviation from t-test in r

Tags: r, t-test, cohens-d

I am looking for how to determine the cohen's d for my t-test so I can make a post-hoc power analysis

take the following:

the data:

```
set.seed(42)
M <- matrix(rnorm(40),ncol=4)
M <- as.data.frame(M)
```

the t-test:

```
t.test.AVB <- t.test(M$V1, M$V2, paired=TRUE)
```

I would like to do a post-hoc power analysis using the following:

```
pwr.t.test(n = 40, d = , sig.level = .05, power = NULL, type = "paired")
```

but to do this I need to calculate cohen's d. I understand cohen's d to be: mean difference / standard deviation.

The t-test outputs the mean difference (.7107535), but how do I find the standard deviation?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you already know the answer: "mean difference / standard deviation" `d <- (mean(M$V1) - mean(M$V2)) / sd(c(M$V1, M$V2))`

Comment: Thanks, I was not finding the sd(c(M$V1, M$V2)) part.